# Pass in For Loop Parameter into Each Statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-maps

I have a JSON feed that is pulling into an each statement.  What I would like to do is the for loop var `i` I would like this value to be used in the each statement.  In the example below the for loop will run 0, 1, 2.  If `i == 1` then I would like to run the JSON feed but only for the `i = 1` value.  Currently when the if statement gets triggered the JSON each statement runs through all the items b/c it's `i` value starts at 0.  So the `console.log` I have in place returns 0, 1, 2.  I would like it to return only 1.  Thank you for any help.

**EDIT**
My focus is to make `$.each(data.DATA, function(i, item) {` the `i` within this each statement to use the number that `i` is equal to in the for loop statement.  So if there are 3 items in the JSON file, only item 1 will be ran.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    if (i == 1) {
        $.getJSON("/json/v2_ilt_map.cfm?feedtype=ILTMAP_SCHEDULED&customerID=1&TrainingObjectParent=3", {}, function(data, i) {
            $.each(data.DATA, function(i, item) {
                console.log(i);
            }
        }):
    }
}​
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to introduce an additional function scope to make this work.

```
function checkOnly(i) {
  return function(data) {
    $.each(data.DATA, function(ii, item) {
      if (ii == i) console.log(ii);
    });
  };
}

for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    if (i == 1) {
        $.getJSON("/json/v2_ilt_map.cfm?feedtype=ILTMAP_SCHEDULED&customerID=1&TrainingObjectParent=3", {}, checkOnly(i));
    }
}
```

Here, the callback passed to `$.getJSON` is created inside another function. By doing that, the variable "i" that's examined in the `.each()` loop is a *copy* of the "i" from the `for` loop.  The handler function therefore has a fixed value to compare against.

Comment: This is looking promising.  Give me one moment to test.

Comment: @HelpInspireMe This is a variation on a common issue. The fact that JavaScript variable scope is only introduced at the function level is a stumbling block for those used to Java, C++, etc.  However, because JavaScript has closures that really work, it's an easy hurdle to get over.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  var x = i;
  if (i == 1) {
    $.getJSON("/json/v2_ilt_map.cfm?feedtype=ILTMAP_SCHEDULED&customerID=1&TrainingObjectParent=3", {}, function(data, i) {
        $.each(data.DATA, function(n, item) {
            if(n == x){
                console.log(n);
                break;// you can use break if you want
            }
        }
    }):
    break; // you can use break if you want
}
```

}​